# Angular2 Filtering an http request

Tags: angular

I wanted to get some advice and guidance regarding filtering an http request in Angular. I have a service that reaches out and grabs the data. The data is then used in an ngFor on the component.

**Data Service Function to Grab the Data**

```
getCycleStages(): Observable<StageContainer[]> {
  console.log('Starting stages');
  const url = this.stagesURL;
  return this.http.get<StageContainer[]>(url, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Then, on the component I import the service and subscribe to the http request.

**Component Function to Subscribe to the Service Function**

```
getStages(): void {
  this.BCS.getCycleStages()
  .subscribe({
    next: (response : any) => this.stages = response['value'],
    error: (e) => console.error(e),
    complete: () => console.log(this.stages)
  })
}
```

This all works, I get the data successfully. But I would like to filter the data I get from the http.get request. I have been searching online and trying different guides and looking at documentation. I have tried to filter in the service we seemed logical to me, as well as on the component, but I'm doing something (probably a lot) wrong.

**Attempt 1 - Filter on the data service.**

```
getCycleStages(): Observable<StageContainer[]> {
  console.log('Starting stages');
  const url = this.stagesURL;
  return this.http.get<StageContainer[]>(url, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    filter(val => val.sName = 'James')
  );
}
```

**Attempt 2 - When I Subscribe on the Component**

```
getStages(): void {
  this.BCS.getCycleStages()
  .subscribe({
    next: (response : any) => this.stages = response['value'].filter(val => val.sName = 'James'),
    error: (e) => console.error(e),
    complete: () => console.log(this.stages)
  })
}
```

Thanks so much for any help or guidance you can offer.

Have a great day!

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: Both of my attempts result in errors.  I am trying to figure out a way to filter my http.get request. Basically, I don't know where to put my filter and I was looking for some guidance.

Comment: First attempt is fine as long as you actually do a compare instead of an assignment so instead of val.sName = 'James' do val.sName ===  'James'

Comment: Why don't you use a pipe to filter the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that you are not making a comparaison in your first solution :

```
getCycleStages(): Observable<StageContainer[]> {
  console.log('Starting stages');
  const url = this.stagesURL;
  return this.http.get<StageContainer[]>(url, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    filter(val => val.sName === 'James')
  );
}
```

It should be working fine then :D

And even better, if you want to reuse your service, pass an optional argument :

```
getCycleStages(filterQuery?: string): Observable<StageContainer[]> {
  console.log('Starting stages');
  const url = this.stagesURL;
  return this.http.get<StageContainer[]>(url, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    filter(val => val.sName === filterQuery)
  );
}
```